# Google map to show chennai (India) using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In the below Javascript code i placed a google map it shows mali but i want to show Chennai(India).I tried but i cannot able to solve this issue.so Please   help me to do this.

```
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(15.508742,-0.500850);

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center: myCenter,
  zoom:5,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myCenter,
  title:'Click to zoom'
  });

marker.setMap(map);

// Zoom to 9 when clicking on marker
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
  map.setZoom(9);
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
```

Comment: `var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(15.508742,-0.500850);` perhaps the latitude and longitude values you've provided are wrong...

Comment: It points to mali but i want to point chennai @ Suvi Vignarajah

Comment: because you've got the wrong lat long in there, simple google search would yield that this is Chennai's lat/long values: https://www.google.ca/search?q=chenna+lat+long&oq=chenna+lat+long&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.6402j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=chennai+lat+long&spell=1 Replace with these values, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates you use on this line :

```
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(15.508742,-0.500850);
```

Are pointing to Mali, just change the numbers to coordinates that are in India.

for [Chennai](https://maps.google.ca/maps?q=chennai+lat+long&safe=active&ie=UTF8&hq=lat+long&hnear=Chennai,+Tamil+Nadu,+India&ll=13.052138,80.251608) , use:

```
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(13.052138,80.251608);
```

Comment: It points to mali.But i want to point chennai